# The most efficient way to access a user objects sub-object?

Tags: logic, parse-platform

In my app I am using the parse framework. The basic breakdown for my current situation is that I have users who can like photo albums or photos individually. If a user likes an individual photo I want to place that photo into a new album specific to that user. That way I can easily retrieve an album filled with any given users liked photos.

I want the logic to be as simple and straight forward as possible and I have come to a conclusion, but I need another opinion to see if that's the best way to do it.

I plan to have a pointer to a 'liked photos' album as an object that is accessible on any user object. That way if a user likes a photo I can set the photoAlbumOwner as that album object on a users profile. Then for future retrieval I just need to find all photos that are associated with that album.

Every other option I have thought about requires me to fetch/search data to find the album for a specific user every time they like a photo. That would not be desirable because it's just extra data needing to be downloaded, which leads to more time.

Is this the best way to go about this or is there another option that would be more simple?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array field called likedPhotos in the _User class and then just add an reference to this liked photo.

Javascript code:

```
function likePhoto(photo) {
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    user.add('likedPhotos', photo);
    user.save();
}
```